# Limiting Framerate on Canvas application

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frame-rate

I have built a *very* basic platform "engine":
[Fiddle Removed]

When you move with the arrow keys - the framerate is mentally fast!

I had tried to limit the framerate by using:

```
var fps = 30;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var interval = 1000/fps;
var delta;
```

Then in the draw function:

```
now = Date.now();
delta = now - then;
if (delta > interval) {
    //redrawing scene here
    then = now - (delta % interval);
}
```

But unfortunetely this still has the same frame rate but the performance decreased (like a frame skip instead of a framerate limit).

Please help me! :(

```
I'll give you a cookie!
```

Comment: Why should the code do anything? all it does is set some variables?

Comment: Edited for clarity... added a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should review your GameLoop function, methinks. As it stands, you're asking for 1000 frames a second. oops!

When I edit it into this, it gives me about 33 fps.

```
    GameLoop: function() { //initialise game loop
        Game.Vars.GameLoop = setTimeout(function() { 
            requestAnimationFrame(Game.Functions.Update, Game.C); 
        }, 30);
    },
```

You had that 30 written as a 1.. :)
Choc-chip, if that's okay. If not, I'll take white chocolate and raspberry!

**EDIT:** Effing Hell, you made it! - gotta love those messages one writes for oneself. :D

Comment: Lovely! Thank you - What do you mean "messages"? * *gives you a choc-chip cookie* * (edit) oh you mean what the old guy says? lol

Comment: Nom Nom Nom. Me like cookies. - In the past (circa IE4), I commonly used 'the Fire trUCK word' instead of "error" - while it certainly helped mitigate the frustration caused by seeing it, it wasn't the most fun to explain to my uni lecturer. :chuckle: - Oh, just saw your edit. Yup, 'zactly. Saw the code first, then after slowing it down I got it said to me.